# c#: Programm doesn't enter AsyncCallback from Socket.BeginReceive()

Tags: python, c#, tcp

I want to send data back and forth in a non-blocking manner (on the c# side) between a python script and a Unity application. The ultimate goal is to send data to the python script, calculate stuff and then send the resulting data back to the unity application.

For testing this is the python script currently just listening, printing anything received and sending back an "ok" string after a received message:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.0.22', 2525))
print("starting listening...")
s.listen(1)
while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
    received_data = recvall(clientsocket)
    clientsocket.send(bytes("ok", "utf-8"))
    print(len(received_data))
    if len(received_data) < 100:
        print(received_data.decode('utf-8'))
```

For testing purposes I started a dummy c# project and [took the Code from here as a starting point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example).

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Text;  
  
// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject {  
    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;  
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 4096;  
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
}  
  
public class AsynchronousClient {  
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 2525;  
  
    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);  
  
    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static String response = String.Empty;  
  
    private static void StartClient() {  
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try {  
           IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.22");
           IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
  
            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  
  
            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect( remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);  
            connectDone.WaitOne();  
  
            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            Send(client,"This is a test<EOF>");  
            sendDone.WaitOne();  
  
            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(client);  
            receiveDone.WaitOne();  
  
            // Write the response to the console.  
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);  
  
            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            client.Close();  
  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
  
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  
  
            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);  
  
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",  
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());  
  
            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
  
    private static void Receive(Socket client) {  
        try {  
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();  
            state.workSocket = client;  
  
            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
  
    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
            Socket client = state.workSocket;  
  
            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);  
  
            if (bytesRead > 0) {  
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));  
  
                // Get the rest of the data.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,  
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);  
            } else {  
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {  
                    response = state.sb.ToString();  
                }  
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                receiveDone.Set();  
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
  
    private static void Send(Socket client, String data) {  
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  
  
        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);  
    }  
  
    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  
  
            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);  
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);  
  
            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  
  
    public static int Main(String[] args) {  
        StartClient();  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

**Here is the problem, that occurs:**

As far as I understand it, the `ReceiveCallback()` Method calls `client.BeginReceive()` which should then again end up in the `ReceiveCallback()` Method and so on, until the incoming bytes are of zero length. I assume this is to be able to receive messages longer than the set TCP buffer size.
As soon as no more bytes are received, `receiveDone.set()` should be called, which means that `receiveDone.WaitOne()` called from `StartClient()` would return. Is this correct so far?

Problem is, after the first time the program enters `ReceiveCallback()` I can see during debugging, that the "ok" Message is received. However, when `client.BeginReceive()` is called, nothing happens and the program basically freezes.

Why isn't the program entering `ReceiveCallback()`? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The server does not close the TCP connection, so the client continues waiting for more data to follow.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Aaaand now I feel stupid :D. Thanks a lot, I've been trying to debug the c# code for the last 3 hours, while the problem is the other side. 
Thank you so much.